# Hacking Bike Lights: SuperNova E3 Pro 2 with a TL3 Pro

Tags: lighting, electronics, taillight

My Challenge (besides trying to overcome the temptation of putting things together that don't quite belong) is trying to get the SuperNova E3 Pro 2 to keep the "parking mode" on with a TL3 Pro taillight.

Technically, the capacitor of the E3 Pro 2 doesn't have the power to keep the TL3 lit when the bike stops (Shimano 6V 3W peak output).

What would solve this problem (theoretically) would be an inline 6V battery, that would sit in-between the front and rear lights, taking a charge from the dynamo, but passing a bulk of the power to the light when I'm riding.

When I come below a very low speed, the dynamo (and capacitor) cut off, leaving the battery to power the rear light for a few minutes (or until the battery or capacitor lose their charge).

So what I would like to find is a battery pack that can take a 6V input charge, with a separate discharge circuit to power the rear light.

Does anyone know of such a product? (which is what I am very much hoping for)

If not, if I were to design this myself (with the help of much smarter people, ones not obsessed with making things work that shouldn't), would anyone else be interested in buying it?

Curious to hear constructive feedback.

Comment: Are you aware that there are tail lights with built-in capacitors toprovide exactly this "stop/park light" feature? And if so, what is it you are trying to achieve that they can't?

Comment: Yes indeed. But the aesthetic of the design drew me to these lights. So I wanted to first explore options to make this combination work, before giving up on this and going with a different product.

Comment: You might try to get one of these park light taillights, pillage everything that is not the actual LED, and put it in between your tail light and your power source. Providing they are similar-ish in power consumption, that should work. No guarantee though.

Comment: Interesting idea. That sounds like a good path to explore. Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: You're welcome! It would be cool if you shared your results here!